# How to use a string defined in project into UILabel defined in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Basically in android studio there is a **string.xml** file in which you can define the strings that you will be using in your project.

Below I am giving the Android examples of how this is done:

String defined in *string.xml*:

```
<string name="lbl_login_banner">Find Professionals</string>
```

In the *layout.xml* (which would be equivalent of `.storyboard`, `.xib` or `.nib`):

```
android:text="@string/lbl_login_banner"
```

Is it possible to replicate this in Xcode version 9.2 or Swift 4.

Comment: Any link or direction will help. Thanks.

Comment: https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881

Comment: @Nitish thank you for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS you have to create `Localizable.strings` file, and inside that file you can define your strings.

```
"lbl_login_banner" = "Find Professionals";
```

How you can use it -

In Storyboard you can use the constant in label value like -
[image]

In Code -

```
myLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(lbl_login_banner, comment: "")
```

You can read [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocalizedstring) on how to use `NSLocalizedString`.

You can follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881) on how to create and use `Localizable.strings` file.

Comment: The in code is working but in storyboard is not working.

Comment: check this - http://samwize.com/2014/04/09/if-your-base-storyboard-with-localizable-dot-strings-is-not-working/

Comment: Now I have two .strings files, i.e. _Localizable.strings_ and _Main.strings_. I have to set the value 'Find Professionals' in 2 places. Kinda inconvenient. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Tried searching for a better solution but I cannot spend any more time on this. I am using the solution provided by you hence marking it right. Thanks for your help.